# Is my cron command good?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I try to clean the logs once a week with this `cron` command:

```
@weekly find /var/log/ \( -iregex ".*\.[2-20]+" -o -iname "*.gz" \) -exec rm {} \; 2>&1
```

Is it good?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this rather than using a log rotation daemon?

Comment: @DopeGhoti No particular reason, I'll find out.

Comment: What does “good” mean in this context? It invites “yes” or “no” answers. Does it remove all and only the files you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[2-20]+` is not the correct way to test if a number is in the range from `2` to `20`. Square brackets in a regular expression just match a single character that matches any of the characters inside it. And `-` in the character set is used to specify a range of characters (e.g. `2-9` or `a-z`); the range `2-2` is the same as just `2`. So `[2-20]+` is equivalen to `[20]+`, matches any sequence of the characters `2` and `0`, such as `2`, `20`, `02`, `2200`, etc.

It should be `([2-9]|1[0-9]|20)`. This matches a single digit from `2` to `9`, `1` followed by `0` to `9`, or `20`.

If you're using GNU `find`, you can use the `-delete` operator instead of `-exec rm {} \;`.

And there's no need to use `2>&1` if you're not redirecting standard output. By default, both standard output and standard error are sent as mail to the user.

```
@weekly find /var/log/ \( -iregex '.*\.([2-9]|1[0-9]|20)' -o -iname "*.gz" \) -delete
```